# C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : authentication timeout not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am having some weird issues with authentication in my app. To preface, it is a C#, ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. Users log in and all controllers have an `[Authorize]` tag.

I am making use of sessions to determine what menu options to show the users and this is working as far as I can tell when the session timer ends. My issue is with the users that are logged in, I'm not using anything special, just the built in Identity provider reading from the SQL Server.

What happens is the authentication never times out even after I stop running the application and start it again, the previously logged in user is displayed as being valid as opposed to making me log in again. I have looked at a number of other questions and articles and based on what I've been seeing I have added the following code to the `Program.cs` file.

For the basis of testing I made the idle timeouts just 2 minutes for both authentication and sessions. My session does expire after 2 minutes but the authentication never expires.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);        
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index/";
    options.LoginPath = "/Home/Index/";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Index/";
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    options.Cookie.Name = ".TOR";
});

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    options.Cookie.Name = ".TORSession"; 
    options.IOTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);        
});
```

Comment: Make sure you're calling `builder.Services.AddIdentity()` before `builder.Services.AddAuthentication()` otherwise the expiration will get overridden.

Comment: Could you please share your `program.cs` details? In addition, you could [`have a look here in the offical document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-session-state) whether your configuration has been set accordingly